# Why does an ice rink use a primary and secondary coolant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy

A normal refrigeration cycle uses one coolant, so why does vapor compression cycle of an ice rink you a primary coolant and a secondary coolant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is a kind of a politically related technicality.

In fact, some ice rinks used to have a direct cooling by a single coolant. They may have operated at higher temperatures and achieved higher pressures as well as higher efficiencies. See the fourth paragraph of [this document](http://people.rit.edu/megite/440IceRink-RefrigerationSystems-Applications.pdf).

However, when one looks what the most appropriate coolant is in such systems, he finds out that it's really either ammonia or [R-22](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorodifluoromethane). The latter causes ozone depletion at 20 times lower rates than other ozone-depleting compounds but even this small amount is unacceptable. On the other hand, R-22 is a 2,000 times more efficient greenhouse gas than CO2 which some people also care about. Due to a combination of building codes, emissions regulations to fight ozone and global warming, and fire regulations, direct coolants ammonia and R-22 are no longer kosher.

There don't seem to be good enough alternatives for direct cooling – which would have similarly favorable thermal properties. That's why one uses a system of two coolants. The primary coolant is a rather harmless compound (which couldn't work as a direct coolant, however) and runs in the tubes beneath the ice rinks and this primary coolant is cooled by a secondary coolant which may be R-22 or ammonia or something even more dramatic because a lower amount of it is needed and it's in a safer environment than on the surface of the rink.